# RESTful webservice exposure to a consumer

Tags: web-services, rest

How would a consumer in a RESTrestful webservice know what method he needs to call and what parameter types it might take to get expected result.??

I have created a REST on my local machine , but now I wonder How would one know about what URIs to access in order to go to a method.??
Please help!!

Comment: You should publish an API and documentation for anyone who wants to use your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned from Dave, you should provide a documentation for your RESTful Service. 
But you can also have a look at [HATEOAS](http://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) which is an interesting approach.